# Adding Button in WPF Custom Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am new to WPF and I am writing a simlpe WPF custom control. Following is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace textbtn
{
    public class CustomControl1 : Control
    {
        static CustomControl1()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1)));
        }        

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //if (test.Width > 50)
            //    test.Width = 0;
            //else          
            //    test.Width = 100;
        }
    }
}
```

My XAML code :

```
<ResourceDictionary
    x:Class="textbtn.CustomControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:textbtn">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Button Content="CButton" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75" Click="button1_Click"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="This is a Test" Foreground="Aqua" Background="AntiqueWhite" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>                    
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I am getting the following error. Please help me in fixing that. Thanks in advance.

Error   1   Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'textbtn.CustomControl1'; another partial declaration of this type exists

Comment: Well the error message is quite explicit. You have defined this class in two places and it is partial in the other declaration. keep just one of them not both.

Comment: I defined only in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
public class CustomControl1 : Control
```

With this:

```
public partial class CustomControl1 : Control
```

Comment: It didn't help. I got the following error. 

Error 1 Partial declarations of 'textbtn.CustomControl1' must not specify different base classes

Comment: it' must be a Control not a ResourceDictionary

Comment: That's what happens when you start with UserControls.